# Collectors.toSet() and HashSet

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Take the following line of sample code:

```
Set<String> someSet = someColletion.stream().map(p -> p.toString()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I want a `HashSet`. Taking a debugger to the code, I am indeed getting a `HashSet`. I had a look at `java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet()` to observe the following code:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Set<T>> toSet() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<Set<T>>) HashSet::new, Set::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_UNORDERED_ID);
}
```

The contract *guarantees* a `Set`, and implementation decides on a `HashSet`; seems reasonable. However, my implementation needs the constant time lookup guaranteed by a `HashSet`, not just any old `Set`. If the implementation of `toSet()` decides to use say a `FooSet`, which is perfectly within its rights, my implementation is compromised.

What is the best practise solution to this problem?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

If you want a guaranteed `HashSet`, use [`Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-).